# Does the Torah-encoded age of the universe match science?

Tags: physics, religion, religious-texts, bible, judaism

Dr. Gerald Schroeder published an article in [Aish.com](http://www.aish.com/ci/sam/48951136.html) about the age of the Universe and the Jewish bible:

> So the only data I use as far as Biblical commentary goes is ancient
>   commentary. That means the text of the Bible itself (3300 years ago),
>   the translation of the Torah into Aramaic by Onkelos (100 CE), the
>   Talmud (redacted about the year 500 CE), and the three major Torah
>   commentators. There are many, many commentators, but at the top of the
>   mountain there are three, accepted by all: Rashi (11th century
>   France), who brings the straight understanding of the text, Maimonides
>   (12th century Egypt), who handles the philosophical concepts, and then
>   Nachmanides (13th century Spain), the earliest of the Kabbalists.

Then he make this claim:

> The calculations come out to be as follows:
>
> • The first of the Biblical days lasted 24 hours, viewed from the
>   "beginning of time perspective." But the duration from our perspective
>   was 8 billion years.
>
> • The second day, from the Bible's perspective lasted 24 hours. From
>   our perspective it lasted half of the previous day, 4 billion years.
>
> • The third 24 hour day also included half of the previous day, 2
>   billion years.
>
> • The fourth 24 hour day ― one billion years.
>
> • The fifth 24 hour day ― one-half billion years.
>
> • The sixth 24 hour day ― one-quarter billion years.
>
> When you add up the Six Days, you get the age of the universe at 15
>   and 3/4 billion years. The same as modern cosmology. Is it by chance?
>
> But there's more. The Bible goes out on a limb and tells you what
>   happened on each of those days. Now you can take cosmology,
>   paleontology, archaeology, and look at the history of the world, and
>   see whether or not they match up day-by-day. And I'll give you a hint.
>   **They match up close enough to send chills up your spine.**

Many Jewish websites make similar claims - that their scholars made biblical predictions in advance of modern science long ago. Is this true?

Comment: Have you considered asking http://judaism.stackexchange.com/ if this interpretation of the Torah is 'kosha'?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

No.

To knock the argument down quickly: the generally accepted age of the universe, according to modern cosmology (using the [ΛCDM model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_CDM_model)) is **13.75 +/- 0.11 billion years**. This doesn't match the 15.75 billion years claimed. (Not sure what happened to the 7th day? Presumably that is another 125 million years that has been forgotten about?)

For further reading: The ordering of the events described in Genesis do not match the ordering of events described by science - certainly not enough to send chills down my spine.

> The Genesis 1 creation account conflicts with the order of events that are known to science. In Genesis, the earth is created before light and stars, birds and whales before reptiles and insects, and flowering plants before any animals. The order of events known from science is just the opposite

- [Skeptics Annotated Bible](http://skepticsannotatedbible.com/science/long.html)

Comment: On third day God supposedly created grass and plants with fruit (not flower). I know this seems to be far fetched, but I want to make the gap air tight here, It's not. Perhaps some kind of plants grow without needing the sun. Without flowers, plants do not need bees or animals. On the 4th he could swing earth to start orbiting the sun.

Comment: The issue here isn't "could God make a plant that doesn't need light?" He has supernatural powers. The issue here is "Does Genesis describe a process compatible with the process modern scientists describe?" No, the length and order are different.

Comment: The length and order are different in your interpretation of the bible. However, the bible is vague and can be interpreted differently. Hence, it become an issue. The bible doesn't say it create flowers on the 3rd day. The bible says God created plants on the 3rd day. So it's not airtight yet. Basically your answer is good but I need something more detail.

Comment: @Jim Thio: Flowers _are_ plants.  Isn't fruit an enlarged ovary from a flower?  If you look at **apples**, although the rest of the flower parts dry up and fall off, you should see that the sepals are typically still present.  (_Additional information; see section 11, subsection g:_  http://mansfield.osu.edu/~sabedon/biol3065.htm#carpel )

Comment: I must take issue with your unqualified final paragraph and quote. To say the Genesis 1 creation account conflicts with science is to apply a very specific interpretation to Genesis 1. There are a number of cosmologists who subscribe to an interpretation of Genesis 1 that fits perfectly within modern understanding of the formation of planets. See [Genesis 1: A Scientific Perspective](http://www.scribd.com/doc/6669364/Genesis-1-A-Scientific-Perspective) (specifically p. 6 and following) for an explanation of this interpretation.

Comment: @Flimzy I seriously doubt that a book written in 1979 can account for our current scientific understanding of the cosmos. E.g. [cosmological inflation was born in 1980 at best](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflation_(cosmology)#Early_inflationary_models). And besides that, the Genesis isn't even sure if man was "created" [before or after the other animals](http://skepticsannotatedbible.com/contra/accounts.html)...

Comment: @Sklivvz: Did you actually read the link before discounting it? Genesis 1 talks very little about the "cosmos," except to _mention_ the stars, sun and moon--it offers no explanation for their literal creation (according to the book). Even so, [the author](http://www.reasons.org/dr-hugh-ross.html) still holds to his views in 2011, and has written several more recent books on the topic. The 1979 book is a much more concise summary than the others, though. If you find fatal flaws in how he says Genesis describes scientific understanding, or his portrayal of scientific understanding, please share.

Comment: @Flimzy, while I concede there could be any manner of interpretations of Genesis, I don't believe that interpreting Genesis 1:11 to be referring to fruiting plants is a "very specific" interpretation, but indeed a widely-held one. I did read your linked book; I find very little of the  argument in there compelling, but I don't propose to critique it in the comments here. Each claim could be given its own question. That said, it probably belongs on http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com rather than here.

Comment: The issue is order, not flowering plants. The claim the sun came after Earth is a matter of interpretation. Ross suggests the sun existed before it was "reported," as Genesis is told from a specific vantage point, not in strict chronological order. In this view it is reasonable to interpret the report of flowering plants and animals in accordance to vantage point as well. The view your final paragraph and quote discount are indeed common, but only in the last 80-100 years, and by no means a majority view among historical Bible scholars. Treating it as "the" view I think is simply wrong.

Comment: @Flimzy you're here :). Yea I stayed away from Christian forum because I feel some of my question there is snobbish. I thought I cooled off for a while. Bible is vague. Let's face it. Atheists like to interpret that in the most politically incorrect way and Christians are obviously the opposite. I think I agree with Flimzy here. We just have to recognize the vagueness. Flowers can't exist before animal but the bible doesn't make that claim. Perhaps, original grass in 3rd day is not green either. The earth is not put toward the sun orbit yet.

Comment: This isn't a question about atheism. Does a supernatural God exist? Off-topic. Does the literal sequence of events in Genesis match modern science? No. (Skeptics Annotated Bible) What if we interpret Day 1 as 8 billion years, halving each "day"? Still no (My answer). What if we interpret the Earth as not being in orbit yet? Still no. What if we change the interpretation of all the words including the order, so it isn't as given? [Shrug] Take it to Hermeneutics.SE.

Comment: I'm not disputing whether the literal sequence of events in Genesis is consistent with science (since the alternate view is the Genesis sequence is the sequence of observation, not of creation). But your answer assumes the the only possible reading of Genesis is that of creation order, and your answer therefore makes a blanket statement that Genesis conflicts with science. Isn't that a bit of a possible straw man? "Genesis conflicts with science, because one possible interpretation conflicts with science."

Comment: Feel free to write an answer from your interpretation anytime

Comment: @Oddthinking see my answer for why I think the error of a couple of billion years is irrelevant here. (Hey, the author even removed ~0.65 billion years with no mention as to why!)

Comment: @Flimzy yep, I read your link and it's a creationist pamphlet.

Comment: @SKlivvz: So which claims from the 1979 "creationist pamphlet" are scientifically invalid by today's understanding?

Comment: @Flimzy They are invalid by any means.

Comment: @Sklivvz: You baffle me.

Comment: Okay this article seems to fit the God of the gap pattern. I am just saying that the gap is still there. As Flimzy said, the extremely vague bible can still be interpreted in ways that fit science.

Comment: @Flimzy - If you want to address the claims brought up in that pamphlet, they'd make a good dozen or so (easily refutable) questions either here (for claims about reality) or on Christianity.SE (for claims about the content of Genesis).  Some highlights: earth-moon system requires a miracle (bad science), order of appearance of animals in the Bible is accurately portrayed (bad scripture), water is exquisitely difficult to keep (bad science), trees bearing fruit doesn't actually mean trees bearing fruit (bad scripture), etc..

Comment: @Flimzy: "the alternate view is the Genesis sequence is the sequence of observation, not of creation" -- observation by whom?

Comment: @KeithThompson: Observation from the vantage point established in Genesis 1:2: "hovering over the waters."

Comment: "the earth is created before light and stars" - not quite. in the beginning Gd created heaven and earth refers to the spiritual world and the physical world. http://www.simpletoremember.com/media/a/RMBBreakneckthroughGenesis1/

Comment: @RayS.: In a literal reading, God creates the Earth in Gen 1:1, Light in Gen 1:3 and the stars in Gen 1:16. I explain in above comments why I am disinterested in individual non-literal readings. Take it to Hermeneutics.SE.

Comment: it is not at all obvious what any of those verses means in this context. this is why there is an oral tradition. but you are not interested...

Comment: example. after all the 6 days of creation, Gen.2:4 "These are the generations of the heavens and of the earth when they were created, in the DAY that the LORD God made the earth and the heavens". "these" i.e. everything before.. in the DAY. i.e. oral tradition - everything was created on "day" 1. see Rashi. Rashi on gen.1:1 also brings the oral tradition stating that the verses are not coming to give the order of creation

Comment: @ray - It's reasonable to stretch the definition of "day" and "night", since the whole point of the question is that it *wasn't* literally 24 hours.  Once you start redefining everything else, though, you quickly leave the realm of the reasonable.  For example, I could choose to interpret "separated the waters" on the second day as separating hydrogen from the rest of the elements, and then "dry land" on the third day as solids (vs. gasses).  But Skeptics.SE can't deal with every possible interpretation, traditional or modern - the question asks about one reading, and the answer addresses it.

Comment: is asked this point here http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/60508/1857

Answer (score 16):

#### The argument is ad hoc.

The core of the argument seems to be along the lines that the "speed" of time has changed. Dr. Schroeder claims that after the Big Bang, time went about a trillion times faster.

> What's exciting about the last few years in cosmology is we now have quantified the data to know the relationship of the "view of time" from the beginning, relative to the "view of time" today. It's not science fiction any longer. Any one of a dozen physics text books all bring the same number. The general relationship between time near the beginning when stable matter formed from the light (the energy, the electromagnetic radiation) of the creation) and time today is a million million, that is a trillion fold extension.
>   <sub>[Schroeder, G. Age of the Universe.](http://www.aish.com/ci/sam/48951136.html)</sub>

To clarify, this is how I understand the argument:

1. Time is relative, and hasn't always "felt" the same speed.
2. For a time unit *t*, we know that it felt like a trillion times longer just after Big Bang than it does now. So, 1 *t<sub>big bang</sub>* = *x t<sub>current</sub>* and we have an approximation that *x* ≈ 10<sup>12</sup>.
3. In Genesis 1, the length of time is 6 *d<sub>big bang</sub>* ≈ 6 * 10<sup>12</sup> *d<sub>current</sub>* which is about 16.4 billion (current) years.

I don't really understand how the author jumps from 16.4 billion to 15.75 billion years. I don't have any idea what these "dozen physics text books" are either. The article cites no sources. Altogether, the argument seems ad hoc.

But the right way to knock the argument down isn't to note that it's off by 20%. Not unless we are certain the ratio *t<sub>big bang</sub>* / *t<sub>current</sub>* isn't also off by the same amount.

The real reason why the argument is invalid is that there does not exist any scientific consensus around the concept "how the 'speed'" of time has changed"<sub>[arxiv](http://arxiv.org/find/all/1/all%3a+EXACT+change_in_the_speed_of_time/0/1/0/all/0/1)</sub>, so it is up to the author to explain this. Despite that **we are not given a description of how the "speed" of time has changed**. Further, in general the argument is just ad hoc.

Comment: I suspect we are agreed that, if you say `real_time = k.f(biblical_time)`, where `f` is an arbitrary function that has no basis in science, and `k` is a constant determined, post hoc, to match modern science's estimates, it is foolish to express surprise that it matches modern science's estimates. It is also unfalsifiable and makes no predictions - hence not of much interest on a Skeptics site.

Comment: @Sklivvz this is mostly a summary of the original article, which I also linked to. Except for the absence of scientific knowledge about how the "observed speed" of time has changed—it's difficult to provide a source for that, but very easy to prove me wrong. I'm basically underlining the assumption the author makes without citing references.

Comment: @Oddthinking that's pretty much what I was trying to say.

Comment: I agree with @Oddthinking, except for the conclusion. Of interest for a skeptics site is, how the trick works, to fool you. k and f origin from thin air, from the necessity, to match what they need to match.

Comment: @dancek: the statement you need to reference is "we don't have scientific knowledge of how the "speed" of time has changed", which is the core of your answer and it's completely unsubstantiated at the moment. Thanks :-)

Comment: @Sklivvz ok, I'm really gonna need help with both that and proving that Tooth Fairy doesn't exist.

Comment: @userunknown: I'm coming back to the argument far too late to add:  Yes, you make a good point. It is of interest to us to point out *how* it is unscientific and *why* it is thus uninteresting to scientists.

Answer (score 12):

I like the other answers, but I like the question so I wanted to give a more complete and thorough answer.  I'd have to say, though I much prefer religious folk contorting their holy books to match science rather than trying to contort science to match their holy books.

So firstly, as Oddthinking points out in his answer, the age of the universe is not some 15 3/4 billion years old. Rather about (13.798±0.037)×10^9 years (as calculated with data [measured in 2013 by Planck](http://www.space.com/24054-how-old-is-the-universe.html) (space observatory).  As I understand it there is a high degree of concordance on this and this number is not likely to be off by much.  Now this would actually be impressive if it wasn't so obviously [post hoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Testing_hypotheses_suggested_by_the_data).  Which makes it kind of funny that's it's as far off as it is, even with such a contrived explanation, they couldn't have gotten closer?

But my spine needs some chilling so let's take a closer look...

**Day 1** (note this is RSV)

> 3 And God said, “Let there be light”; and there was light. 4 And God saw that the light was good; and God separated the light from the darkness. 5 God called the light Day, and the darkness he called Night. And there was evening and there was morning, one day.

The first obvious problem is there is the earth.  So actually light did exist before the stars.  It seems the first photons formed after about 1 micro second. God's a fast talker.  But that pesky earth...  But there is what's called the photon epoch which lasts from about 10 seconds after the big bang until about 380,000 years.  Matter like hydrogen, helium and some lithium was created in this time but no stars yet.

[image: universe formation graphic]

**Day 4** (I know 2 comes next, God doesn't)

> 14 And God said, “Let there be lights in the firmament of the heavens to separate the day from the night; and let them be for signs and for seasons and for days and years, 15 and let them be lights in the firmament of the heavens to give light upon the earth.” And it was so. 16 And God made the two great lights, the greater light to rule the day, and the lesser light to rule the night; he made the stars also. 17 And God set them in the firmament of the heavens to give light upon the earth, 18 to rule over the day and over the night, and to separate the light from the darkness. And God saw that it was good. 19 And there was evening and there was morning, a fourth day.

So on the fourth day God made two great lights (a single star and a.. moon?) and a lesser light ([~10^29](http://www.space.com/26078-how-many-stars-are-there.html) "greater light"s). We are firmly still in the first 8 billion years here. Note that stars are still being born and dying but the first stars will be in the [first billion years](http://phys.org/news/2005-09-ferreting-stars.html).  Star formation is actually quite beautiful, even if there are some artificial colors in there. Note that some elements like gold, [can only be produced in the death of a star](http://phys.org/news/2013-07-earth-gold-colliding-dead-stars.html). So stars were born and died before our planet ever formed.  So there is that pesky earth...

[image: stellar nebula]

**Day ?** (I have no idea what day to call this, it's all over the place.)

So the next thing that happens is the formation of our star(day 4). This would have happened about 9 billions years after the big bang [or about 4.6 billion years ago](http://www.windows2universe.org/our_solar_system/formation.html). A [protoplanetary disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protoplanetary_disk) would have formed around the new sun which much of would collapse into planets (planets like Venus would probably be day 4, considered stars).  The earth would have formed from this (day 1).  There is [various hypotheses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origin_of_the_Moon) about the origin of the moon but I believe the most accepted hypothesis right now states that a planet, [Theia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theia_(planet)) smashed into the proto-earth. [The collision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_impact_hypothesis) ejected the earth's crust into orbit, some of which consolidated into the moon(day 4).

[image: protoplanetary disk]

**Day 2**

> 6 And God said, “Let there be a firmament in the midst of the waters, and let it separate the waters from the waters.” 7 And God made the firmament and separated the waters which were under the firmament from the waters which were above the firmament. And it was so. 8 And God called the firmament Heaven. And there was evening and there was morning, a second day.

There would have been some Hydrogen and Helium in the earth from the start, this doesn't tend to stick around. But, as the earth cooled [our atmosphere would have formed](http://www.ux1.eiu.edu/%7Ecfjps/1400/atmos_origin.html) (day 2) then clouds would have formed and rained down on the earth forming the oceans(day 1).  This seems to have been about [4.4 billion years ago](http://www.geology.wisc.edu/zircon/Wilde_et_al.PDF)(pdf).

[image: early earth]

**Day 5** Sorry day 3, you have to wait until later.

> 20 And God said, “Let the waters bring forth swarms of living creatures, and let birds fly above the earth across the firmament of the heavens.” 21 So God created the great sea monsters and every living creature that moves, with which the waters swarm, according to their kinds, and every winged bird according to its kind. And God saw that it was good. 22 And God blessed them, saying, “Be fruitful and multiply and fill the waters in the seas, and let birds multiply on the earth.” 23 And there was evening and there was morning, a fifth day.

Ok the Bible isn't interested in the origin of life, that stuff's boring. So skipping forward a few billion years of microscopic life and ignoring the birds for now, we'll come back to them, we find those watery swarms.  [Animal life seems to have arose](http://www.ucmp.berkeley.edu/vendian/ediacaran.php) [around 575 million years ago](https://pantherfile.uwm.edu/sdornbos/www/PDF%27s/Chen%20et%20al.%202002.pdf)(pdf) and indeed it was in the ocean. But things really got kickin' about 30 million years later in the [Cambrian radiation](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3861885/) (a period of about 20 million years where rapid diversification of animal life took place).

[image: early cambrian life]

**Day 3**

> 9 And God said, “Let the waters under the heavens be gathered together into one place, and let the dry land appear.” And it was so. 10 God called the dry land Earth, and the waters that were gathered together he called Seas. And God saw that it was good. 11 And God said, “Let the earth put forth vegetation, plants yielding seed, and fruit trees bearing fruit in which is their seed, each according to its kind, upon the earth.” And it was so. 12 The earth brought forth vegetation, plants yielding seed according to their own kinds, and trees bearing fruit in which is their seed, each according to its kind. And God saw that it was good. 13 And there was evening and there was morning, a third day.

Skipping over the dry land bit as it was covered in the formation of oceans. We're interested in the plants. But we need to ignore the talk of seeds, fruit and trees.  Following a [series of extinction events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cambrian%E2%80%93Ordovician_extinction_event) we are brought to the Ordovician era where we see the first plants. Plants will continue diversifying and evolving until flowers emerge after even mammals.

[image: first land plants]

**Day 6**

> 24 And God said, “Let the earth bring forth living creatures according to their kinds: cattle and creeping things and beasts of the earth according to their kinds.” And it was so. 25 And God made the beasts of the earth according to their kinds and the cattle according to their kinds, and everything that creeps upon the ground according to its kind. And God saw that it was good.
>
> 26 Then God said, “Let us make man in our image, after our likeness; and let them have dominion over the fish of the sea, and over the birds of the air, and over the cattle, and over all the earth, and over every creeping thing that creeps upon the earth.” 27 So God created man in his own image, in the image of God he created him; male and female he created them. 28 And God blessed them, and God said to them, “Be fruitful and multiply, and fill the earth and subdue it; and have dominion over the fish of the sea and over the birds of the air and over every living thing that moves upon the earth.” 29 And God said, “Behold, I have given you every plant yielding seed which is upon the face of all the earth, and every tree with seed in its fruit; you shall have them for food. 30 And to every beast of the earth, and to every bird of the air, and to everything that creeps on the earth, everything that has the breath of life, I have given every green plant for food.” And it was so. 31 And God saw everything that he had made, and behold, it was very good. And there was evening and there was morning, a sixth day.

[note that the following is a brief simplification and overview of life since the Cambrian radiation to give you a feel for it. It's not as well cited just linked up to Wikipedia. It's uncontroversial so I hope there's no problem].
[Some more extinction events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordovician%E2%80%93Silurian_extinction_events) bring us to the [Silurian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silurian). In the Silurian we get diversification of jawed and bony fish and the first terrestrial animals, some arthropods. And then the [Devonian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devonian) where we get land plants and further diversified fish. [Another extinction event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_Devonian_extinction), then the [Carboniferous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carboniferous) brings us amphibians. Then after [an extinction event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carboniferous_rainforest_collapse) we get the [Permian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permian) where we have the mammals and reptiles, this is capped off with [the earth's largest extinction event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permian%E2%80%93Triassic_extinction_event) finally killing off the trilobites.  Then we find ourselves in the [Triassic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triassic) where we see the first seeds, corals, and a lot of different (what we might recognize as) dinosaurs.  [Another extinction event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triassic%E2%80%93Jurassic_extinction_event) and we are in the well known [Jurassic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jurassic) where you get the (true) dinosaurs.  In a lovely turn of events no major extinction event happens and we are brought into the [Cretaceous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cretaceous), finally it starts looking a bit more like home with the first flowering plants, recognizable insects like butterflies. Then we have [probably the most well known extinction event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cretaceous%E2%80%93Paleogene_boundary) and it brings us to the [Paleogene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paleogene) where mammals and birds diversify and we see the first grass.  Again, not characterized by a major extinction event we find our selves in the [Neogene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neogene), birds and mammals continue to diversify and we see the first hominids.  This is followed by the [Quaternary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternary) period which takes us through the last 2.6 million years of the earth's history and of course the development of humans and the domestication of cattle.

[image: Day 6]

Comment: Slightly off-topic: No, the Bible is not literal in any way, but people probably wouldn't've understood evolution, so instead of complicating it with the cambrian explosion, he just gave them a vague explanation. Yep, people were dumb back then.

Comment: Actually from what I've read, brain mass has decreased since the agricultural revolution.  They were possibly sporting more cognitive power than us.  But without proper education systems or an understanding of the scientific method, they really had no hope of testing or really even recognizing wacky claims.  Your view seems to be pretty new though, perhaps trying to reconcile science with faith?  This wouldn't have been a problem before science!  Anyway, I'm glad we can both agree people shouldn't try to use the Bible as a science textbook.

Comment: @JamesLu I don't know why I always forget to tag.

Comment: @AdamPhelps The descrease in brain mass is more of the "fight or flight" in our amygdala.

Comment: @AdamPhelps I just think people didn't have enough science back then.

Comment: @JamesLu  We could all use more science!

Comment: @AdamPhelps Yeah, like how they did during the Renaissance.